# Is there a way to obtain coefficient matrix A and RHS b of constraints equation from cplex or guribi in python?

Tags: modeling, gurobi, nonconvex-programming, docplex, julia

I have a non-linear program, minimizing sum of concave functions subject to linear constraints. Hence I'm using a different solver(in Julia). However, that solver assumes we have constraints in $Ax \le b$ form and requires me to pass $A$ and $b$ as input parameters. This is very inconvenient as I explicitly do not have these matrices.
Since the constraints are linear, I plan to build them in cplex or gurobi and export the coefficient matrix $A$ and right hand side $b$ in some file and then import and read them in my NLP solver.

So, is there a way to extract $A$ and $b$ from the cplex model?
I'm using docplex and guribipy.

Also if there is a better way to resolve this, I'm all ears.

Comment: That looks like a difficult and error-prone approach to me. You could translate the problem into Pyomo format, which supports different (local and global) NLP and MINLP solvers. With NLP and MINLP problems, it is always a good idea to try out different solvers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have a particular method from a Stanford paper I want to implement. My problem is not convex NLP that solvers can solve and for non-convex problems the solver just give a feasible and local optimal solution. I want global optimum.

Comment: There are global NLP solvers.

Comment: They are either for convex programming or they use some heuristic to find a local optimal for non-convex problem. I know of itopt, Knitro, snopt and minotaur nlp solvers. The idea to check with different solvers comes in handy there because a different heuristic may lead to a different locally optimal solution and it's worth exploring different solvers to get different solutions to pick best among them. I want to solve globally and therefore can't rely on these solvers. I have an algorithm and it has convergence and complexity proofs. I would prefer that I think : )

Comment: *They are either for convex programming or they use some heuristic to find a local optimal for non-convex problem.* Sorry, this is just not correct. There are quite a few global NLP solvers that give global optimal solutions for nonconvex problems. I use them myself.

Comment: Can you share the solvers? And perchance would you happen to have convergence and complexity proofs for the underlying algorithms?

Comment: Global solvers include Baron, Antigone, Octeract, Couenne, Scip, Lindo. These are deterministic global solvers enhanced by a lot of heuristics. So complexity is really not a useful measure (just like for MIP and CP solvers).  Some of the algorithms are written down in published papers, but often lots of details are not (especially for the commercial solvers).

Comment: Did you consider using the Xpress solver? As of version 9.0 this has a global solver that can solve non-linear problems to global optimality. The Python API of the Xpress solver is similar to that of CPLEX and Gurobi.

Answer (score 1):

In gurobi, you can use [`model.getA()`](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_geta.html) query to get the linear coeff matrix in sparse format.
You can get list of linear constraints using `model.getConstrs()` & also get attributes like [rhs](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/rhs.html), [lhs](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_getrow.html) & [sense](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/sense.html).
You can output the model in python through `model.write('filename.mps')`. You can read in a model through `model.read()`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that, when you build the model, you assign names to all constraints and variables and to the objective function. CPLEX (and I'm pretty sure Gurobi) can export the model to a text file in [MPS format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPS_(format)). You can write code (in Python or Julia) to create the required matrices, initially filled with zeros, and then read in the MPS file, parse it, and plug the entries in it into the correct slots in the matrices.